# Hamiltonian graphs and card shuffles

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I am solving the example on Hamiltonian graphs:

> We have **3 players** of unique a game, there are **57 special cards**. We know
>   that by the rules of the game we can play only react to one card by 30
>   cards. At the start of the game every player has **received 19 cards**. The
>   game is played in clockwise manner a -> b-> c ->a. When the player has
>   **no card he can play** as reaction to previous card, he **drops out**. We
>   also know that the card relations are symmetrical ( A -> B then we can
>   play B -> A ).
>
> Is it possible for person who knows the rules to create such shuffle
>   of the cards that game will end on 19th turn with no dropout players ?

I deduced from it that the graph has $57$ vertices and $30$ nodes. Is this deduction correct? How to go from there?

Comment: I deduced from it that the graph has 57 vertices and 30 nodes. Is this deduction correnct ? how to go from there...

Comment: You will need to clarify the question. It sounds like you are dealing with a 57 vertex 30-regular graph. But the question is not clear. Is the question about whether all such graphs allow all cards to be played (has a Hamiltonian path?) Or whether some such graph allows all cards to be played? Do you mean there is one way for the players to play all cards? Or that no matter how they play the cards, they will play them all?

Comment: The question is if the Ham. path exists. And the second no matter how they play them ... if they are able not to drop out it is correct ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Hamiltonian path in every 57 vertex 30-regular graph. See [Dirac's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac%27s_theorem).